# Rails 4 - HTML in Helper Returning a Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, methods, helper

Trying to create a simple helper that returns this to my view:

```
<hr id="effects">
```

The helper I created looks like this:

```
def bar(id)
  content_tag(:hr, id: id)
end
```

When I call

```
<%= bar("effects") %>
```

The helper correctly displays the `<hr>` but the id is being displayed directly to the page like `{:id=>"effects"}`

I am assuming I am doing this wrong, but can't seem to find anything that can help me. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`content_tag(name, content_or_options_with_block = nil, options = nil, escape = true, &block)`

the second param is content, you can try

```
def bar(id)
  content_tag(:hr, "", id: id)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag)

```
def bar(id)
  content_tag(:hr, "", id: id)
end
```

However, I wonder why you have created a helper method for this. You can do it directly on views (its recommended also).